# Template function on struct members

Tags: c++, templates, struct, switch-statement

Is there a way to code a single template function able to run on different members of a given `struct` ?

A **wrong** example would look like :

```
struct Foo
{
  int a, b;
}

template <MEMBER x> //which does not exist 
cout_member(Foo foo)
{
  cout << foo.x << endl;
}

int main()
{
  Foo foo; 
  cout_member<a>(foo);
  cout_member<b>(foo);
  return 0;
}
```

I imagined an answer based on a switch, but I then wondered if this switch would be tested on run-time (what I would like to avoid) or on compile-time ?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: I'm solving a system of coupled partial derivative equations for a 2D grid, and I'd like to have a single space derivative function for all the physical quantities of each cell... Or at least to reduce the number of functions to copy/past !

Comment: Seems superfluous and cumbersome possibly an XY problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As long as you want to pick up a data member from a set of data members having the same type, you can use a pointer to data member:

```
template <int Foo::*M>
void cout_member(Foo foo)
{
    std::cout << (foo.*M) << std::endl;
}
```

And use it as:

```
cout_member<&Foo::a>(foo);
```

If you want to indicate also the type, you can do this:

```
template <typename T, T Foo::*M>
void cout_member(Foo foo)
{
    std::cout << (foo.*M) << std::endl;
}
```

And use it as:

```
cout_member<int, &Foo::a>(foo);
```

---

Just out of curiosity, the second snippet would be even simpler in C++17:

```
template <auto M>
void cout_member(Foo foo)
{
    std::cout << (foo.*M) << std::endl;
}
```

See it up and running on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pjidcpDbkEvDAr2P);

Comment: Thanks ! I'll take the C++17  version !

Comment: Of course ! I am sorry I tried some houres ago but it just took me a long time to understand how to do it... Is it ok now ?

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage `std::mem_fn` so you don't even have to care: (untested)

```
template < typename Fun, typename ... Params >
void print(Fun f, Params && ... p) { std::cout << f(std::forward<Params>(p)...) << "\n"; }

print(std::mem_fn(&Obj::fun), Obj());
```

Since you're using streams you probably don't care...but this should add little to zero overhead from just writing `cout << obj.fun()`.

Edit: `mem_fn` works on data members too.  Creates a callable that returns a reference to the value that you can then use: `int x = mem_fn(&pair<int,char>::first)(my_pair);`

Comment: Fair enough. I misunderstood the answer. Thank you.